# SQL Counting column number based on first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am using SQL Server 2012

Suppose I have the following table

```
1       2           3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
Client1 1/31/2017   a                           y
Client1 1/31/2017   b                       n   
Client1 1/31/2017   c           1               
Client1 1/31/2017   d       2                   
Client1 1/31/2017   e                   0
```

I am transforming data from one table into a different format in a second table.

The column headers happen to be numbers just like is shown 1-10.

The transformation logic is fairly simple except the column the value will be placed in depends on the value in column 3 which are shown as letters.

This is a simplified example. In the real example there can be as many as 86 columns.

I was going to do this with a `CASE` statement, but the only way I can think of to force the data into a specific column is to enter a bunch of `NULL` values with commas.

Is there a way instead to say, for example if the value of column 3 is 'a' then place the value in column 10, if the value of column 3 is 'b' then place the value in column 9 and so forth?

I'd rather designate the column by number then have to count out forced spacing with `NULLS`

So for example I would write something like

```
CASE WHEN 3 = a then NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,value
WHEN 3 = b then NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,value
ELSE NULL END values
```

But again I'd prefer if I could do something like

```
WHEN 3 = a then (put the value in column 10)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear on your desired results

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([1] varchar(25),[2] date,[3] varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Client1','1/31/2017','a'),
('Client1','1/31/2017','b'),
('Client1','1/31/2017','c'),
('Client1','1/31/2017','d')


Select [1],[2],[3]
      ,[4] = case when [3]='g' then [3] end 
      ,[5] = case when [3]='f' then [3] end 
      ,[6] = case when [3]='e' then [3] end 
      ,[7] = case when [3]='d' then [3] end 
      ,[8] = case when [3]='c' then [3] end 
      ,[9] = case when [3]='b' then [3] end 
      ,[10]= case when [3]='a' then [3] end 
 from @YourTable
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: @JayC Happy it helped.  I was worried that I completely missed your intent